# Update RecyclerView não atualiza o item na lista

Tags: android, lista, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, adapter

Tenho um simples recyclerView e o adapter abaixo onde faço o CRUD antes de salvar em BD, e tudo funciona exceto o update, onde atualizo o item pelo adapter porém a visualização na lista não atualiza os dados. Caso clique no mesmo item para edita-lo novamente ele mostra os valores que já foram atualizados e não os mostrados na lista.

Abaixo meu adapter:

```
public class InsumoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InsumoAdapter.InsumoViewHolder>{

   
    private final Context context;
    private List<Insumo> insumos;


    public InsumoAdapter(Context context, List<Insumo> insumos) {
        this.context = context;
        this.insumos = insumos;
    }

    @Override
    public InsumoAdapter.InsumoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_teste, viewGroup, false);
        InsumoAdapter.InsumoViewHolder holder = new InsumoAdapter.InsumoViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    public static class InsumoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView tNome, tVlrCusto;
        ImageButton btnDelete;
        CardView cardView;
        public InsumoViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            tNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeProd);
            tVlrCusto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtValorProd);
            btnDelete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnDel);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardProduto);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final InsumoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(insumos.size() != 0){
            final Insumo p = insumos.get(position);
            holder.tNome.setText(p.getNomeInsumo());
            holder.tVlrCusto.setText(p.getValor().toString());

            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicou no Card para Editar na posição "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    //bundle.putString("nome", p.getNomeInsumo());
                    //bundle.putDouble("valor", p.getValor());
                    bundle.putInt("position", position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    //update(p, position);
                }
            });

            holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicou no Card para Excluir na posição "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    delete(position);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.insumos != null ? this.insumos.size() : 0;
    }


    private void excluirInsumo(Context context, final int i){
        String titulo = "Excluir";
        String msg = "Deseja excluir este item?";
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(titulo);
        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Sim",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //deleta("Pproduto",produtos.get(i).get_id());
                        AddActivity addActivity = new AddActivity();
                        //addActivity.deleta(i);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Não",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void delete(int position){
        insumos.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void update(Insumo insumo, int position){
        insumos.set(position, insumo);
        //notifyItemChanged(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void insere(Insumo insumo){
        insumos.add(insumo);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

É como se não tivesse voltando no onBindViewHolder para atualizar os dados. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Sei que deve ser algo bobo, mas não consigo encontrar de forma alguma.

Comment: `notifyItemChanged(position);` não tá indo?

Comment: pq `//update(p, position);` no onClick está comentado?

Comment: Me desculpe Murilo, o notifyItemChanged(position); não funcionou e o update esta comentado porque eu chamo a activity e de lá que chamo o update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que fique como registro para ajudar quem também esteja com o mesmo problema, o meu era que eu não estava com a mesma instancia quando eu chamava o update. A solução foi criar uma classe que, na Activity do meu recycler após instanciar o adapter eu dou um set e depois na Activity de update eu dou um get, de forma que eu tenha sempre a mesma estancia do adapter.
classe que recebe e disponibiliza a instancia do adapter:

```
 private static InsumoAdapter insumoAdapter;

    public static InsumoAdapter getMainAdapter(){
        return insumoAdapter;
    }

    public static void setMainAdapter(InsumoAdapter adapter) {
        insumoAdapter = adapter;
    }
```

setando a instancia

```
 mInsumoAdapter = new InsumoAdapter(getBaseContext(), insumos);
        //setando o adapter na classe
        setMainAdapter(mInsumoAdapter);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mInsumoAdapter);
        mInsumoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

pegando a instancia para o update

```
insumoAdapter = getMainAdapter();
```